# How do I fill Landsat 7 SLC gaps using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, gdal, landsat, nodata

I am currently using the QGIS 3.4.0 `Raster -> Analysis -> Fill nodata` (a tool for Landsat 7 data).

I am using the directly downloaded USGS tiff band files with corresponding gap mask band tiffs as input and specifying the output as a tiff file both directly onto my desktop and as a temp file.

I receive the same error in regard to the layers not being generated correctly. I have tried with and without default validity mask. The script is below:

```
Results: {'OUTPUT': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':C:/Users/townl/Desktop/band1test.tif, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>} Loading resulting layers The following layers were not correctly generated.<ul><li>C:/Users/townl/Desktop/band1test.tif</li></ul>You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```